# Security vulnerabilities in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, security, redirect

I am using this simple `.htaccess` file to redirect everything from my domain to my website's subdirectory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /SITE/ [L]
```

However, I was told by a colleague that this could cause security vulnerabilities due to the fact that it will redirect everything to the sub-directory.

I was wondering: Is there any truth in that, and if so what (if any) ways are securing the `.htaccess` file further? I have relatively little knowledge about what vulnerabilities actually exist which is why I am asking this. I Googled this looking for various answers but website hacks are no simple matter so it is not apparent for me, without understanding more about what the Rewrite Engine does, what potential problems could result.

Comment: Every time you hear something is "a security vulnerability" or "a performance issue" ask them to elaborate. Otherwise - who knows what they meant. There really is nothing wrong with this rule.

Comment: Thank you! That is good to hear.